# How to override user agent stylesheet in Chrome and show my design Correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

My design for `table` show correctly in Firefox but It doesn't show correctly in chrome because of user agent style sheet and my code doesn't override to default style of chrome how I can do it well?

```
<table class="mytable-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>family</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>juli</td>
            <td>2015/3/3</td>
            <td>California</td>                         
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
.mytable-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .mytable-responsive thead th{
        display:block;
        border:none;
    }
    .mytable-responsive tbody tr td {
        display: block;
        border:none;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give  `!important` to override the code

use this code

```css
.mytable-responsive {
    width: 100% !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
  .mytable-responsive thead th{
    display:block !important;
    border:none !important;
  }
  .mytable-responsive tbody tr td {
    display: block !important;
    border:none !important;
  }    
}
```

```html
       <table class="mytable-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>family</th>
                        <th>date</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>juli</td>
                        <td>2015/3/3</td>
                        <td>California</td>                         
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```